# ActiveMQ - Cost of creating temporary queues

Tags: performance, activemq-classic

I would like to use queues dynamically generated in ActiveMQ to serialize the handling of events generated by multiple sources.

I need this to be sure that updates on the same record are never in conflicts.

The problem is that I need a different queue for each set of updates that relate to the same record.

There could be in theory millions of records and, of course, I do not want to create millions of queues.

Ideally, a queue should be created when necessary and destroyed when all the updates are completed.

The events that fire the updates are asynchronous but are still correlated. I know that when something happens, several events will be fired in the same time.
It is practically a small burst of asynchronous but correlated updates.
After some time, the queue generated could be deleted.

I understand that there is a cost in creating and deleting queues, but am I right thinking that the cost of generated and deleting these queues with a rate that, during a peak, won't be higher than a few queues per seconds, won't create performance issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a cost of temporary queues but generally not that high unless you have high network latency between app server and broker and you should be fine.

Temporary queues, though, have some limits. Such as they are deleted once the created connection goes down. So, if you want your job to resume after a system restart, don't depend on temp-queues. I advice against dynamically creating regular queues at multiple/sec rate. The system is not designed for that.

Generally what you want to do while processing a group of related messages is to utilize [message groups](http://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html). That way, you can use a single queue that does not depend on the producer/temp queue creator connection.

Comment: I probably used the name "temporary" incorrectly. I only meant that I want to delete them after a short period of time. They cannot be temporary queues that are deleted when the connection is closed. I will try to use the message groups.

Comment: Having said that, going back to my original question, if I create and delete real queues (not temporary), would this introduce too much cost?

Comment: There are things going on when creating destinations. Like the advisory system where there are a few topics created per destination and messages are sent when new consumers/producers go/leave, statistics measurement etc. On the other hand, there are possibilities to turn off advisories and automatically Garbage collect unused queues. This is, again, not the intended way to use ActiveMQ, but you might get away with it. Benchmark - your mileage may vary.